# Ajax.ActionLink duplicating and inserting the entire view into a <div> inside that view

Tags: c#, ajax, actionlink

I am new to MVC and working on an e-commerce application for my aunt's business. I have a Product List page with a partial view to display a menu to search by category. It all worked just fine with Html.ActionLink helpers, but when I switched to AJAX, it updates the products but inserts the entire List view into the div that I want updated(header and everything included). I'm assuming it has something to do with the UpdateTargetId I defined, or perhaps the layout(I'm no css whiz). So here goes:

ProductController:

```
public ViewResult List(string category, int page = 1)
    {
        JProductListViewModel model = new JProductListViewModel
        {
            JProducts = repository.JProducts
                .Where(p => category == null || p.Category == category)
                .OrderBy(p => p.ProductID).Skip((page - 1) * PageSize).Take(PageSize),
            PagingInfo = new PagingInfo
            {
                CurrentPage = page,
                ItemsPerPage = PageSize,
                TotalItems = category == null ?
                    repository.JProducts.Count() :
                    repository.JProducts.Where(x => x.Category == category).Count()
            },
            CurrentCategory = category
        };
        return View(model);
    }
```

Menu Partial:

```
@foreach (var link in Model)
{
    <div class="catmenuitem">
    @if (link != null)
    {
        @Ajax.RouteLink(link, "", new { controller = "Product", action = "List", category = link, page = 1 }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, 
    UpdateTargetId = "List", LoadingElementId = "loading", LoadingElementDuration = 1000 },
    new { @class = link == ViewBag.SelectedCategory ? "selected" : null })
    }
    </div>
}
```

List View:

```
<div id="List">
    @foreach (var p in Model.JProducts)
    {
            Html.RenderPartial("ProductSummary", p);
    }
</div>
```

The result I am getting is the entire List.cshtml view being duplicated and inserted into the "List" div. I have a feeling it will be some sort of silly mistake, but I can't seem to find it.

Thanks,
Kwinsor5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must create a new partial view for your List view, name it _List. Then change your List view to include _List partial view and change your List controller to return _List partial view in case of AJAX request.

**List partial view _List:**

```
<div id="List">
@foreach (var p in Model.JProducts)
{
        Html.RenderPartial("ProductSummary", p);
}
</div>
```

**List View:**

```
<div></div>
@Html.Partial("_List", Model)
<div></div>
```

**Change in List Controller:**

```
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            return PartialView("_List", model);
        }
```

Now you can have different elements in List view and its parial view

Comment: Thank you! I ended up having to use if (Request.IsAjaxRequest()) return PartialView(model) else return View(model). This works as long as I put the other div's I had in the List view into the layout or their own partial. Do you know of another way to fix my issue without having to do that? Or it quite possibly could have been poor design on my part.